# Facebook App Invite get number of Invites sent android

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, cordova-plugins, user-experience

Is there a way to get number of invites that were sent using the facebook on android.

Here is a use case, I want the user to invite **at least** 3 friends. Doing so will unlock a feature.

How do I get the number of app invites sent.

Comment: _“Doing so will unlock a feature”_ – that is not allowed. You can not reward users for sending out invites (because that encourages them to _spam_ their friends, instead of sending out invites only to people they think might actually be interested in your app); at most you can reward _successful_ invites, i.e. when an invited user joins your app, you can reward the user who invited them. // You should go read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).

Comment: "when an invited user joins your app, you can reward the user who invited them" This is what I meant..Is there A sample code where this is implemented?